# Bash split word with same characters

Tags: bash

How can I split string which contain more of the same characters.

For example `name=John:adress=London`. I need result `name` as variable and `John:adress=London` as value.

I have no idea how to. Thanks.

Comment: Is not clear. Is your string exactly like this `name=John:adress=London` ? All in the same line, separated by `:`?

Comment: Text is exactly: name=John:@(ADDRESS=(LONDON=(STREET=XY))) and all is same line.

Comment: And what /how you want to split this line?

Comment: Using user input as a variable name is insecure. What if the input contains `IFS=...`

Comment: Split into two strings. First string "name"  and second string "John:@(ADDRESS=(LONDON=(STREET=XY)))".

Comment: `cut -d= -f1` for first string, `cut -d= -f2-` for second string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

```
# print first field 
echo "name=John:@(ADDRESS=(LONDON=(STREET=XY)))" | cut -d = -f 1
# print remaining fields 
echo "name=John:@(ADDRESS=(LONDON=(STREET=XY)))" | cut -d = -f 2-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cut and command grouping

```
INPUT='name=@(ADDRESS=(LONDON=(STREET=XY)))'
NAME=$(echo "$STR" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
INFO=$(echo "$STR" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
```

The single quotes in the first line prevent any special bash symbols to be interpreted literally. The variable `$NAME` accepts the value of a command grouping, signified by `$()`. The `$INPUT` is echoed into the `cut` command, where the delimiter `=` is specified by the `-d` flag, and the first field (`-f` flag) is specified.

Next, the variable `$INFO` is assigned the value of the command grouping, where the second field until the end is signified. The dash after the two in this part: `-f 2-` tells bash to select everything after the first `=` sign to the end.

The first equals sign will not be in the `$INFO` variable at the end.